# Is it possible to include external javascript on a per-post basis in Ghost?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ghost-blog

I'm running an installation of Ghost and am trying to include a Google Charts chart into a single post. Doing so would however require me to load Google's javascript first.

This should of course be possible by adding the `<script>` tag to `/content/themes/casperdefault.hbs`, but I'd rather not load it globally, but just if necessary on a per-post basis.

Is this in any way possible? Adding the code directly into the post body at least doesn't seem to have much of an effect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a script tag in the post body in the editor should in fact work. In Ghost 0.4, the following results in an  alert box with `object`:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.3.0/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script>alert(typeof window.Handlebars)</script>
```

Comment: You're right, that actually does work. I guess the issue lies in Google's way of using a div container `<div id="chart_div"></div>` to hold the chart? I'm guessing my original question is pretty much useless then.

Comment: Copying & pasting the head and body sections from [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start) works fine for me: http://i.imgur.com/SCXkOkb.png Note that JS is only executed in the post list and on the frontend, not in the editor preview itself.

Comment: Just extending onto this question a little, the above works if you have an absolute link to the js file, however what if you want to include a js file from your ghost assets folder? The handlebars method does not seem to work in this case...
    
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset "app/js/custom-page.js"}}"></script>

Comment: @ScottAlexander I am pretty sure that posts can't use handlebars helpers, but you can simply provide the full path (`/assets/app/js/custom-page.js`, prepend subdir if you configured one).

Comment: Cheers, looks like I was over complicating things trying to get the root address to append onto.

Comment: On the one hand, that looks very exciting and opens up the possibility of building highly dynamic blogs very quickly. On the other hand, wouldn't that increase the risk of XSS vulnerabilities? It substantially lowers the cost for hackers to infect sites...